# template different return types

Tags: c++, templates

In the code below, I have to cast to TDestination for boolean_cast to avoid a compiler warning (truncation from 'VARIANT_BOOL' to 'bool').  Is this a compiler issue or a C++ issue?

```
template<typename TDestination, typename TSource>
TDestination boolean_cast(TSource source)
{
    TDestination destination;

    static_assert(std::is_same<TDestination, bool>::value || std::is_same<TDestination, VARIANT_BOOL>::value, "destination must be bool or VARIANT_BOOL");

    //convert to bool
    if (std::is_same<TDestination, bool>::value)
    {
        if (source)
            destination = true;
        else
            destination = false;
    }
    //convert to VARIANT_BOOL
    else
    {
        if (source)
            destination = (TDestination)VARIANT_TRUE;
        else
            destination = (TDestination)VARIANT_FALSE;
    }

    return destination;
}
```

Comment: why do you use VARIANT_ in the first place?

Comment: It's neither. A type is the same type in both branches of the `if` statement, even if surrounded by template mumbo-jumbo. If your `TDestination` is `bool`, it's `bool` inside the `else` branch too, even though its code is not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @n.m. said in a comment, the compiler doesn't stop compiling the false branch of the `if` so both branches must be valid code when the destination type is `bool` and when the destination type is `VARIANT_BOOL`.

You can avoid that problem by dispatching to a helper template that is partially specialized on the destination type e.g.

```
template<typename TDestination, typename TSource>
struct boolean_cast_impl;  // undefined

template<typename TSource>
struct boolean_cast_impl<bool, TSource>
{
    static bool cast(TSource source)
    {
        return source ? true : false;
    }
};

template<typename TSource>
struct boolean_cast_impl<VARIANT_BOOL, TSource>
{
    static VARIANT_BOOL cast(TSource source)
    {
       return source ? VARIANT_TRUE : VARIANT_FALSE;
    }
};

template<typename TDestination, typename TSource>
TDestination boolean_cast(TSource source)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<TDestination, bool>::value || std::is_same<TDestination, VARIANT_BOOL>::value, "destination must be bool or VARIANT_BOOL");

    return boolean_cast_impl<TDestination, TSource>::cast(source);
}
```

Or even just defining constants of the correct type in the specializations:

```
template<typename TDestination, typename TSource>
struct boolean_cast_values;  // undefined

template<typename TSource>
struct boolean_cast_values<bool, TSource>
{
    static const bool true_ = true;
    static const bool false_ = false;
};

template<typename TSource>
struct boolean_cast_values<VARIANT_BOOL, TSource>
{
    static const VARIANT_BOOL true_ = VARIANT_TRUE;
    static const VARIANT_BOOL false_ = VARIANT_FALSE;
};

template<typename TDestination, typename TSource>
TDestination boolean_cast(TSource source)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<TDestination, bool>::value || std::is_same<TDestination, VARIANT_BOOL>::value, "destination must be bool or VARIANT_BOOL");

    typedef boolean_cast_values<TDestination, TSource> values;
    return source ? values::true_ : values::false_;
}
```

Comment: KH: I'm using VARIANT_BOOL because it's required by an external COM interface
JW: Thanks for solutions